# C++ class pointer without giving template parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates, variables, pointers

Hello dear people of the underworld called the internet.

Lets say we have a class called X with the template parameters(Y):

```
template<class Y>
class X
{
    //...
};
```

And i wanted to create an instance of the class without(not yet) template parameters, and then define the pointer WITH the template parameters:

```
X* myClass;

//....
myClass = new X<variable>();
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Well, **in any way**, yes: `void *myClass;` then `myClass = new X<whatever>;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X is not a type without its template argument so no, unfortunately not. You could achieve what you want if X had a base class which defined the interface you wanted to use though.

For example,

```
struct Interface
{
    Interface() {}
    virtual ~Interface(){}

    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

template <class Y>
class X : public Interface
{
    //...
    virtual void doSomething() override;
};

std::unique_ptr<Interface> myClass;

//....
myClass.reset(new X<variable>());
myClass->doSomething();
```

Comment: `X` is not an incomplete type. It's the name of a template, not a type at all. An incomplete type is a type that has been declared but not defined, like `class C;`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'll fix that up.

Answer (score 3):

No. A pointer points to a type, and `X` is not a type.

Answer (score 2):

Not with `X*`. Consider this alternative:

```
class BaseX { 
    //...
};

template<class Y>
class X : public BaseX
{
    //...
};
```

Since `BaseX` is a complete type, you can have `BaseX*` that references some `X<Y>` once you've defined it.